# Bootstrap: Vertical toolbar to house btn-group-vertical groups

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

So, I was looking through the bootstrap documentation for a solution to this one and didn't find anything. Is there a way, using bootstrap components, to display button groups vertically one after another?

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
  <div class = "btn-group-vertical" id = "A">
    buttons...
  </div> <!-- button group --> 
  <div class = "btn-group-vertical" id = "B">
    buttons...
  </div> <!-- button group -->
  <div class = "btn-group-vertical" id = "C">
    buttons...
  </div> <!-- button group -->
</div> <!-- button toolbar -->
```

This essentially makes:

```
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
...
```

when I actually want:

```
A1
A2
A3
... (Break in Toolbar)
B1
B2
B3
... (Break in Toolbar)
C1
C2
C3
```

If not in bootstrap itself, there is probably a way to make this happen with CSS if anyone has an idea how to do that. Thanks in advance!

---

Editted for Clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the top Div with btn-toolbar and just use btn-group-vertical

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">A1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">A2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">A3</button>
    <br /><br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">B1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">B2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">B3</button>
    <br /><br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">C1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">C2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">C3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make this entirely clear, I actually want a toolbar group with spacing between the button groups. The buttons in groups A, B, and C are not related, except that they perform actions in the same frame, so I don't think it would be appropriate to attach them all to one another without some way to distinguish their general purpose... I could always color them differently, I guess?

Comment: Just add a Break tag or two after each set

Comment: Yup, that did it... can't believe I didn't think of that :/

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't totally do it, since the buttons next to the breaks won't get the proper rounded borders (the group sets a border radius to the first and last childs)